# Fubini's theorem and marginal measure

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact domain or manifold, $Y=\mathbb{R}$. Let $\rho$ be a borel propability measure on $Z=X\times Y$

For every integrable function $\phi: X\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a version of Fubini's theorem states that:

$$\int_{X \times Y} \phi(x,y)d\rho = \int_X \int_Y \phi(x,y)d\rho(y|x)d\rho_X.$$

Now, with this setting we define a function $f_\rho:X\rightarrow Y, f_\rho (x)=\int_Y y d\rho(y|x)$.
What follows is a trick, which I dont understand:
$$\int_{X\times Y} (f(x)- f_\rho(x))^2d\rho = \int_X (f(x)- f_\rho(x))^2d\rho_X$$ for all $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should have $\displaystyle\int_{Y}d\rho(y|x)=1$. Then apply the Fubini theorem to $\displaystyle
\int_{X\times Y}(f(x)-f_{\rho}(x))^{2}d\rho$.

Comment: I considered this as a possibility. But I don't see, why this always holds.

Comment: You know there is a theorem for the disintegration of measure, and keep in mind that $Y={\bf{R}}$ is a Borel field.